# How to make browser download file from xhr request

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I'm sending `xhr` request to server to download a file. I'm including authorization token into the request so I can't download a file without using `xhr`. What steps should I take to make browser download a file when response from the server is received? And what headers should the server include?

Comment: You can stuff the server response into a data URL, put it on an `<a download>` and trigger a click. Note that the `download` attribute is [not well supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=download). Or, you can use a normal form submit (not XHR), sending your token in a hidden input instead of in a request header.

Comment: @Amadan, thanks. These are the only options, right?

Comment: I won't say that - but the only ones I can think of.

Comment: It seems that [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23797348/2545680) might do?

Comment: Yes, that's the code for "stuff the server response into a data URL, put it on an `<a download>` and trigger a click".

Answer (score 8):

This is a piece of code that works for me. Im using it for testing so its not the cleanest way I guess. But it can show a picture.

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    var downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(xhttp.response);
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.style = "display: none";
    a.href = downloadUrl;
    a.download = "";
    a.click();
}
};
xhttp.open("GET", fileUrl, true);
xhttp.responseType = "blob";
xhttp.setRequestHeader('Authorization', token);
xhttp.send();
```

This piece is not crucial, I was just need it in my case:

> xhttp.setRequestHeader('Authorization', token);

This link can be usefull as well: [Sending and Receiving Binary Data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data)